# FB social Comment moderation is not working

Tags: php, facebook

Don't why I not able to enable the moderation function for Facebook comment social plugin.
Below is my sample code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<meta property="fb:app_id" content="2864989547252XX"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="Site Name"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="News"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com/"/>

<meta property="og:locale" content="en_MY" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Site Name"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Product Description."/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
FB.init({
    appId  : '2864989547252XX',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
});

</script>

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.example.com/discussion4.php?cat=eb1ca31c1b38bb6c42af6844d5f994d1&amp;topic=5429e70a452e033c398769660b582e4c" data-num-posts="20" data-width="480"></div>
```

Could anyone assist me on this? The comment box is working fine but moderation option didn't show out.

I have added to the logged in FB user as Apps Admins and comment moderator.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will need to specify an app id in the og: tags.  Then you will have to have your moderators listed as admins for the app.

You might also need to have your moderator "like" the url too.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I think I did specify an app id, it is something like this "<meta property="fb:app_id" content="2864989547252XX"/>". I have tried to add "<meta property="fb:admins" content="100001258580000"/>", but still not working. Beside, the fbid i have added in fb:admins is a verified user and in the app settings role is admin too. Also I have added this user in http://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments as a moderator too ... but the moderation option still not appearing.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this for ages, try putting this tag in on your page ...

```
 <html xmlns:fb="http://yourwebsite.com">
```